# White gap after Stack Overflow website toolbar with Desktop mode displaying by using iPhone Safari

Tags: support, bug

Most of the times I use Stack Overflow website with *Request desktop mode* on iPhone Safari which I got used to Stack Overflow website like I'm using on my laptop everyday by Google Chrome.

But lately, this is what I see when I open Stack Overflow website on iPhone Safari ***with Desktop mode***:

[image]

As you can see, there is **a white gap** after `Toolbar` which clearly shows that the `Toolbar` is not getting fixed by screen and it ends in a point which never should be.

- I have also tested **Enable-Disable Responsiveness** but unfortunately, it didn't work.
- I have also checked other similar questions but none mentioned about this.

Is that a bug? How can we fix it?

**Edit:**

I'm using IOS 12 (beta 11). Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: The profile pages are not yet responsive, it's still being worked on (I assume).

Comment: I just checked with other layouts. it seems like it's the only page which is not getting fit with mobile browsers. But other layouts automatically switches to mobile mode (responsive) when i open them.

Comment: off topic, but nice username.  i don't know what sounds those characters make but they look awesome

Comment: Please note that the name of the site is Stack Overflow (two words, both with initial capital letters). Also, in English, the word I, when used to refer to yourself, is always capitalized.

Comment: Still the same issue ...